# MacBook won't get past purple startup screen

Tags: boot, macbook

16.04 installed on my 2013 MacBook Pro for 6 months or so with no issues. At setup time I encrypted the computer (for no reason other than it seemed like a cool idea). In the past few weeks it was telling me I had almost run out of memory, which was odd because I definitely haven't filled it up. I don't use it for 6 weeks, and come back to it, and I try and power it up, and get stuck on the original purple screen. No text/terminal comes up. I have tried booting off a USB, with no luck. Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you have installed?

Comment: I have 16.04 installed.